# c# regex no white spaces - characters - underscore

Tags: c#, regex, whitespace

I'm trying to figure out how to filter with regex the following examples

```
"  test  " -> no
"test" -> yes
"test_test" -> yes
"test123test" -> no
```

I'v tried to figure it out with the numerous topics on here and the REL reference but I only got absolutely confused and lost!

```
@"^[^a-zA-Z\s]{2-40}$"
@"^[^\d\s]{2-40}$"
```

both are letting through white spaces everywhere.

Also I wan to fit in a underscore filter but just _ not every special characters.

help pls and if you could reference me some documentation too it would be grate!

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you need. If you need to match 2 to 40 symbol string that may contain ASCII letters and `_`, use `^[a-zA-Z_]{2,40}$`

Comment: Why don't you use String.Trim Method

Comment: As for the trimming method, it won't help with *"test123test" -> no*

Comment: ah thanks! ^[a-zA-Z_]{2,40}$ did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match 2 to 40 symbol string that may contain ASCII letters and `_`, use

```
^[a-zA-Z_]{2,40}$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z_%5D%7B2%2C40%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=%20%20test%20%20%0D%0Atest%0D%0Atest_test%0D%0Atest123test&o=m)

C# declaration:

```
string pat = @"^[a-zA-Z_]{2,40}$";
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[a-zA-Z_]{2,40}` - 2 to 40 (as `{2,40}` is a [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)) chars that are lower- or uppercase ASCII letters or `_` symbols (the `[...]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) construct matching just 1 char)
- `$` - end of string anchor

Comment: I added some links to documentation and reference pages.